# Jquery How to use .click() to update a variable and pass that variable to an array or add it to another variable

Tags: jquery

I am a first time user of this site so please excuse my mistakes.  I'm simply trying to use a .click() to update a var called "v1PackCharge" based on 4 custom buttons that could be clicked.  The problem I'm having is that I am unable to get the variable outside of the .click() for me to use in a calculation further down in the code.  Is what I'm trying to do possible using the .click() or is there an easier way to do this?  I could just use check boxes, but I would really like to be able to use my custom buttons.

```
var v1PackCharge;
$('#v1BasPkBTN, #v1IntExtPkBTN, #v1FamFlydPkBTN, #v1FulDetPkBTN').click(function(){
    if(this.id == 'v1BasPkBTN'){
        v1PackCharge = totalBasic;
    }else if(this.id == 'v1IntExtPkBTN'){
        v1PackCharge = totalIntExt;
    }else if(this.id == 'v1FamFlydPkBTN'){
        v1PackCharge = totalFamousFloyds;
    }else if(this.id == 'v1FulDetPkBTN'){
        v1PackCharge = totalFullDetail;
    }else {
        v1PackCharge = 0.00;
    }
});
alert(v1PackCharge);
```

Comment: what does `alert` show? Move it inside the `click` handler. The variable will only become defined after `click` handler executes. Before that the variable will stay undefined. Your calculation code should be invoked from inside the `click` handler function.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to declare v1PackCharge at all if you just want to alert the values in the click event. All you need to do is this

```
$('#v1BasPkBTN, #v1IntExtPkBTN, #v1FamFlydPkBTN, #v1FulDetPkBTN').click(function(){
    if(this.id == 'v1BasPkBTN'){
        alert(totalBasic);
    }else if(this.id == 'v1IntExtPkBTN'){
        alert(totalIntExt);
    }else if(this.id == 'v1FamFlydPkBTN'){
        alert(totalFamousFloyds);
    }else if(this.id == 'v1FulDetPkBTN'){
        alert(totalFullDetail);
    }else {
        alert(0.00);
    }
});
```

if you really do need v1PackCharge for other functions or other usage you can do this instead. Move the alert function into the click event

```
$('#v1BasPkBTN, #v1IntExtPkBTN, #v1FamFlydPkBTN, #v1FulDetPkBTN').click(function(){   
     if(this.id == 'v1BasPkBTN'){            
            v1PackCharge = totalBasic;            
        }else if(this.id == 'v1IntExtPkBTN'){            
            v1PackCharge = totalIntExt;            
        }else if(this.id == 'v1FamFlydPkBTN'){            
            v1PackCharge = totalFamousFloyds;            
        }else if(this.id == 'v1FulDetPkBTN'){            
            v1PackCharge = totalFullDetail;            
        }else v1PackCharge = 0.00;

        alert(v1PackCharge); 
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ah4hM/

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a separate function check the value of `V1PackCharge`. Calling alert immediately after binding the click events will just yield an undefined V1PackCharge value in an alert box when the page loads.

Here is a modified example showing the global variable `V1PackCharge` getting set. By the way, I would also run `this.id` through a `switch` statement instead.

**Javascript**

```
var v1PackCharge;
$('#one, #two, #three, #four').click(function(){
    if(this.id == 'one'){
        v1PackCharge = 1;
    }else if(this.id == 'two'){
        v1PackCharge = 2;
    }else if(this.id == 'three'){
        v1PackCharge = 3;
    }else if(this.id == 'four'){
        v1PackCharge = 4;
    }else {
        v1PackCharge = 0;
    }
});

$('#checkV1').click(function() {
    alert(v1PackCharge);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" id="one" value="one"/>
<input type="button" id="two" value="two"/>
<input type="button" id="three" value="three"/>
<input type="button" id="four" value="four"/>
<input type="button" id="checkV1" value="check var"/>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/45SdJ/

Answer (score 0):

In this case the alert will show `undefined` since it is executed before the actual click happens.

But the value of `v1PackCharge` is globally set, you can use it outside the click handler. Only thing is you need to modify the test case

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wmmmb/)

Answer (score 0):

I dont see the need for the var v1PackCharge unless you are using it to hold some value. Because right now you are just hard coding values to it. If you just move the alert inside the click() it would return the values.